# A regex for a list

Tags: python, regex

I'm using python and `re`.
I have a string that looks like this:

```
[AddrPart(value='Something cyrillic', type='something'), AddrPart(value='Something else', type=None), ...]
```

I have a regular expression that can capture the whole group:

```
r"\[AddrPart(.+)\]\t"
```

and another one, that captures a part of it but then fails:

```
\[((AddrPart\(value=[-а-яА-Яё']{1,20}), type=(None|.{1,}))\)\]\t
```

This one gets everything from the first `type` to the end of the string before the `\)\]`.

What I want is to get all the `AddrPart`s in the list.
I feel like I'm missing something basic and obvious. What might that be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default regex returns greedy matches (largest possible match) and you want it lazy. Add `?` to the part between the `()`:

```
(AddrPart\(.*?\))
# Match 1: "AddrPart(value='Something cyrillic', type='something')"
# Match 2: "AddrPart(value='Something else', type=None)"
```

If you want it without the outer part of the `AddrPart` then:

```
AddrPart\((.*?)\)
```

---

To get both the `value` and `type` you can add a bit more:

```
AddrPart\(value=(?<value>.+?),\s*type=(?<type>.+?)\)
# Match 1: Group `value`: 'Something cyrillic', Group `type`: 'something'
# Match 2: Group `value`: 'Something else', Group `type`: None
```

Comment: Oh. That's it, basically. Hopefully, I'll manage parsing out the `type`s and `value`s myself.
Thanks

Comment: @Chiffa - you are welcome :) I also added a version to retrieve the value and type parts